# Lines in box aren't wide enough to give box max-width of 30em ...?

Tags: css

I'm trying to dev my first responsive site and I've got a (css) 'problem' with this page > http://www.amordetango.nl/txp/agenda

When scaling the window to mobile width the background (.png) of `article` is as wide as the inner lines go ... and that's **not** how it suppose to work.

But I want the background as wide as the width of its responsive container (#main) ... !? ... it's common CSS I guess, but I can't figure it out.

[edit]
It's suppose to work like this > http://jsfiddle.net/redfox52/jknH4/ ... but it isn't! I can't find anything in the css files that causes this strange(!) behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

At last ... I found that `#main` has a `float:left;` ... skipping that and everything is back to normal ... :)

Fiddle last revision > http://jsfiddle.net/redfox52/jknH4/5/